# Cannot execute clone on Response - response body already used in service worker for caching

Tags: javascript, fetch, service-worker, google-material-icons

This error only occurs when I try to load google's material font icons.

Expected behavior: it loads the font icons and caches them for offline use

Actual behavior: it errors out and sends a 408 and gives the title as an error

running in chrome on windows on localhost.

https://pastebin.com/S863bT4w

```js
/// <reference no-default-lib="true"/>
/// <reference lib="esnext" />
/// <reference lib="webworker" /> 
/**@type {ServiceWorkerGlobalScope} self */

async function fastget({req}) {
    cache_res = await self.caches.match(req)
    if (cache_res) {
        if (req.url === cache_res.url) {
            return cache_res;
        }
    }

    try {
        network_res = await fetch(req)
        // checks whether to cache or not
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}

self.addEventListener('install', ev => {
    ev.waitUntil(self.caches.open('basecache').then(cache => {
        cache.addAll(stuff_to_be_cached).then(() => {console.log('Installed!')})
    }))
    ev.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting())
})

self.addEventListener('activate', ev => {
    ev.waitUntil(self.clients.claim())
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', ev => {
    ev.respondWith(fastget({
        req: ev.request
    }))
})
```

[image: error]

Comment: It's a CORS request. you need to clone the response first

Comment: I did try to clone it but that's what the error is. It isn't letting me clone.

Comment: Could be due to hoisting? try using `const` for `network_res`

Comment: Oh that was it thank you so much! Just one more question: why did that work?

Comment: Since it worked by making a const declaration, it probably was holding the reference to older response object. But that doesn't make sense. Maybe someone else can explain better